# Trouble with Python: Opening an app/saving a file

Tags: python, file, path, operating-system, save

I am a bit new to coding, I am trying to improve my skills. My preferred programming language is python. But I do need help with this bit of code. I am making an app called User Helper for my own use. I know that the code may look a bit sloppy, but when I posted it in for some reason I put four spaces in but it didn't turn to a block of code, so I had to manually put in the spaces.

But back to the topic at hand, my code has 2 problems (though you could probably find more.) I am not able to save my favorites to a document for later use when I open the app again. As well I don't know the code to open an app from python code.

I have tried many different methods including using the os function. I think I may need some sort of directory, but I'm sorry to say I am unfamiliar with directories and I have had trouble with them. The time function will be used later in the project. And for some reason when I run this program, it tries to find a path from the folder all my coding projects are in.

I also want to thank you for reading this, and I hope I can get this solved soon. I plan to become an active member in this community, and I can't wait to continue improving my skills in coding.

Thank you for your time!

```
import os
import time

def name():
  print ""
  print ""
  print "Welcome to User Helper!"
  name1 = raw_input("What is your name?  ")
  print ""
  print "Welcom to User helper "+name1+"!"

def favorites():
  print ""
  print "Now opening Favorites settings..."
  fav1 = raw_input("Favorite 1: ")
  fav2 = raw_input("Favorite 2: ")
  fav3 = raw_input("Favorite 3: ")
  fav1full = fav1+".app"
  fav2full = fav2+".app"
  fav3full = fav3+".app"
  fav1_path = os.path.abspath(fav1full)
  fav2_path = os.path.abspath(fav2full)
  fav3_path = os.path.abspath(fav3full)
  os.system(fav1_path)

name()
favorites()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.chdir()` to change default  directory and `os.startfile()` to open the program or file directly. As for saving it for later use, if you want to save it to a text file, I'll include it in my answer.

Comment: ok, thank you so much! But that also adds another question, how/what would I change the default directory with?

Comment: What is the problem? `os.chdir("path to the folder")` will change your working directory. That done, you can say `os.startfile("some_fav_app.app")` and start it as it would be started on mouse click, if that is your goal, if I understood it correctly.